# Script to enable/disable IPv4 on a specific network adapter Win 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, script, batch-file

For reasons I don't wish to get in to at the moment I need to occasionally disable Internet Protocol Version 4 (IPv4) on my wireless card, then enable it some time later.

Currently I go into the wireless cards properties and un-check IPv4 and apply it.

Later I will go into that same property screen and re-check the IPv4 box then disable/enable the network adapter to get an IP address.

Is there any way to automate the un-checking/re-checking the IPv4 box?

Thanks
~Mike

Answer (score 0):

you could do this in powershell like so:

```
Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name MyAdapter -DisplayName "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)"
```

I know your question states batch file, but save this with a .ps1 extension and it should do what you need it to.

Comment: Also, just to note... Enable-NetAdapterBinding will reverse this.

Comment: What version of PowerShell is needed for this? I tried on version 4 and I got `Enable-NetAdapterBinding : The term 'Enable-NetAdapterBinding' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.`